# Constraint not deleting in Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

*I am unable to delete constraint in StoryBoard when not using Size classes and only using Autolayout in iOS 8.0*

Comment: you can select the constraint and delete that. its not a problem

Comment: Yes i tried it but not able to delete it

Comment: how are you deleting and selecting?

Comment: I am selecting the constraint but not able to delete it

Comment: Select constraint -> Just a press delete key from keyboard.

Comment: I am deleting but its not deleting from storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Please follow as below:-

1. Select any one ViewController from your story board.
2. Go to File Inspector.
3. And uncheck Use size Classes.

One dialog box appear, and select as per your requirement.

**Or Else**

You can delete from ViewController also.

Comment: I am selecting the constraint in storyboard and deleting it but not able to perform the deletion